# Can not access the 3rd table in laravel 5 in 3 tables have relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have these table

```
- users table

  id  name  password

- keywords table

  id   name  user_id

- groups table

  id  name  keyword_id
```

I want to retrieve logged in user groups

```
$groups = Group::with(['keyword' => function($query){
              $query->where('user_id' , Auth::user()->id)
          }]);
```

but all groups return NOT that groups for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `whereHas`

```
$groups = Group::whereHas('keyword', function($query)
{
    $query->where('user_id' => Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```